# VMWare Remote debugging using Visual Studio 2010 Vista host and Win2000 guest

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, vmware, remote-debugging, vmware-workstation

I have Visual Studio 2010 in a Vista host and I'm trying to debug a C program in a Windows 2000 guest. Apparently there is no normal way to do that because VS2010 no longer supports Windows 2000 CRT. So what I've done is I'm using the msvsmon from VS2008 instead:
`C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\Remote Debugger\x86\msvsmon.exe`

I have set the right firewall settings I think. I can connect to the guest machine on the host by doing \192.168.114.128\c$ for example with no problem.
When I click the VMWare play button in visual studio to debug msvsmon will start in Windows 2000 but that's it. There is a series of dings and then a message box. I am not logged in as the same user name on the host as I am as the guest. Is that really necessary? Does anyone have experience in this area or good diagnostics?

There is an option in the guest msvsmon where I can disable authentication but I still can't execute using the play button.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use no authentication and then use the attach to process option in Visual Studio?  You need to start the app in the Windows 2000 box first.

Comment: I experienced a lot of remote debugging problems and they had to do with firewalls and no netbios. The VMWare instructions must be followed to a T. As far as Windows 2000 goes I haven't tried again.